# Passing values with space between from php to javascript onClick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am failing to find the answer for this and it is taking me long
This is my problem: I want to pass php variable to javascript onclick but i am failing if there is space between the value of the variable for example passing first name and last name in one variable is not working but passing one username is working.

This is the code:

```html
       //$username='Liberty Johnson';//This one is not working
       $username='LibertyJohnson';
     <tr>
     <td><b>
     <?php echo $username?>
     </b> is online now <a href="javascript:void(0)" 
      onclick=  "javascript:chatWith('<?php echo    $username?>')"> 
      Start Chat</a>
      </td>
      </tr>
```

```
    function chatWith(chatuser) {
        createChatBox(chatuser);
        $("#chatbox_" + chatuser + " .chatboxtextarea").focus();
    }
```

Comment: What are you doing in `chatWith` ?

Comment: function chatWith(chatuser) {
 createChatBox(chatuser);
 $("#chatbox_"+chatuser+" .chatboxtextarea").focus();
}

Comment: Maybe that can help@MurtazaKhursheedHussain

Comment: $("#chatbox_"+chatuser+" .chatboxtextarea") - it can't find object, that you looking for

Comment: Would help to see the "rendered" code from what the php outputs to make sure there is no formatting issues.

Comment: the problem is `"#chatbox_"+chatuser+" .chatboxtextarea"` will rended to `"#chatbox_John Doe .chatboxtextarea"` which doesn't exist in your HTML.

Comment: That's not going to work; if you expand your `chatuser` variable you'll see that the JQuery selector becomes `$("#chatbox_Liberty Johnson.chatboxtextarea")` i.e. it's looking for an element called `Johnson` with a class of `chatboxtextarea` inside an element with the id `chatbox_Liberty`

Comment: In chatWith function, use this code `function chatWith(chatuser) { createChatBox(chatuser); $("#chatbox_"+chatuser.replace(" ", "")+" .chatboxtextarea").focus(); }`

Comment: Basically i am trying to pass values with space between them to the javascript using onclick function  thats all i need to be solved nothing to do with the whole of my code. Can you tell me how to solve space between values please.

Comment: `onclick=  "javascript:chatWith('<?php echo    str_replace(" ", "", $username)?>')">`

Comment: @Leereal You need to remove the space `#chatbox_Liberty Johnson.chatboxtextarea` is not a valid element. Replace spaces with underscores or remove altogether.

Comment: @ Medet Ahmetson Atabayev your solution worked well let me try to solve with this one although the true value is not being passed to the javascript function.

Comment: @Wobbles okay okay id names do not contain spaces i see where the problem is not thanks hey. Its only that i am new to javascript.

Comment: @Leereal Its not a JS issue, you would run into this issue with CSS too. spaces in class names indicate multiple classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to change `white space` to `&nbsp;`. So you can use

`<?php echo str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $username); ?>`

instead of

`<?php echo $username; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
function chatWith(chatuser) {
    createChatBox(chatuser);
    $("[id='chatbox_" + chatuser + "'] .chatboxtextarea").focus();
}
```